# Minecraft Forge: my Mod Jar file does not load a json library that I used in my code and it does not load one of my GUI textures

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I wrote my Minecraft Mod in Forge (version 1.7.10) and I used a json library in my project, as well a custom GUI. However, after I built my .jar file using
./gradle build in the terminal, I installed my Mod in Minecraft by putting it in the mods folder of Minecraft. My mod is recognised in the game and my custom blocks show up. However my custom GUI's texture is not loaded and one of my Java libraries that I used in my project (org.json) is not being recognised. I built my .jar file many times but apparently it doesnt include this library. Is there something wrong with my './gradle build' terminal command? By the way, when I run Minecraft Forge using Eclipse, everything works fine.

Comment: More detail about your enviorment would be helpful, MC version, forge version, etc.

Comment: The version of Minecraft Forge is 1.7.10 and when I use Minecraft, I just use my profile and i use Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 in my profile to run the Mod. Let me know if you want a screenshot of the error when the game crashes. Thank you for your help !

Comment: And here is the crash error message: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject"

Comment: sorry, I meant edit it into the question so people can help you. I personally have no expirrence working with custom GUI textures. I've only done blocks and items for fun.

Comment: Thank you, I added the modification now :)

Comment: Minecraft already uses a JSON library (GSON) which will be packaged with the game by default, so you might not want to include a redundant one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build.gradle add this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

This will copy all the jars in your libs folder into your jar.

that should do it.

if you have something that requires native libraries(for example sqlite)

```
jar {
    from('native') {
        into('org/sqlite/native')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alright, so Here is what I wrote in my build.gradle:

"dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
}"
After that I wrote the three commands in the terminal: 
"./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --refresh-dependencies"
"./gradlew eclipse"
"./gradlew build"
Then I put the Mod jar file in the mods folder of minecraft. But still, the game crashes when i use that json library. It says:
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject"
Thank you for your help by the way, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Did you put the json jar in the libs folder?

Comment: Yes, I have put the json jar in the libs folder inside the /build folder. The hierarchy is like this: /build/libs/json-20160212.jar

Comment: I was thinking maybe there is a problem with my own gradle. Should I update it to the latest version? my current version is 2.0.
I also don't understand how the google-api library works but the json library does not..

Comment: No, place it in a libs folder thats on the same level as the build.gradle file. http://i.imgur.com/Eq1y3Kg.jpg

Comment: Alright, so that's not what I was doing in the beginning. so I put the json jar file in the libs folder that is in the same level as the build.gradle. I built the Mod file again but I still get the same crash error.. 
Just to make sure, there is a build folder in the same level as build.gradle and it contains another libs folder which contains the modid-1.0.jar file, right?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tschallacka/59661633c9f1a279fc290ff89d5fd6c6 thats my build.gradle. The compiled mod will be outputted to `build/libs/yourmodname.version.jar`  you basically dont want to put anything in the build folder. Not sure whats going wrong. can you post your build.gradle in a gist, and a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: Here is the build.gradle gist: https://gist.github.com/SaraFatih/f86315f4c4e291615a8599894b45763c

And here are the screenshots of the folders: http://imgur.com/a/mwTL1

Comment: Everything seems in order. If you rename your compiled mod to .zip instead of .jar and extract it, does the org.json folser appear anywhere? also, remove the compile org.json part(https://gist.github.com/SaraFatih/f86315f4c4e291615a8599894b45763c#file-build-gradle-L36). you dont need it if you include all the jars in your libs folder ;-) that might lead to a conflict too.

Comment: I see, I removed the compile org.json part. But how can I rename the compiled mod to .zip instead of .jar? :) Is it some property i should change in build.gradle? because when i just tried to rename the mod file as .jar, it didn't want to be uncompressed..

Comment: No, .jar==.zip just rename the extension part.

Comment: Alright, I did that and here is a screenshot of the files inside: http://imgur.com/6c6Kv7l 
There is no libs folder nor any json jar file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109427/discussion-between-michael-dibbets-and-sarafatih).